# How to set null to a GUID property

Tags: c#, guid, nullable

I have an object of type Employee which has a Guid property. I know if I want to set to null I must to define my type property as nullable `Nullable<Guid>` prop or Guid? prop.

But in my case I'm not able to change the type of the prop, so it will remains as Guid type and my colleague and I we don't want to use the Guid.Empty.

Is there a way to set my property as null or string.empty in order to restablish the field in the database as null.

I have a mechanism to transform from string.empty to null but I will change many things if the would change to accept a empty guid to null.

Any help please!

Comment: A `Guid` is a `struct`, those can't be null. You need to use the nullable type. Either using `Guid?` or `Nullable<Guid>`. There is no other way.

Comment: When I see something like "I know I should do this but I can't", stop right there. Yes you can and you should. Why would you cause yourself a world of hurt by hacking stuff?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> Is there a way to set my property as null or string.empty in order to restablish the field in the database as null.

No. Because it's non-nullable. If you want it to be nullable, you have to use `Nullable<Guid>` - if you didn't, there'd be no point in having `Nullable<T>` to start with. You've got a *fundamental* issue here - which you actually know, given your first paragraph. You've said, "I know if I want to achieve A, I must do B - but I want to achieve A without doing B." That's impossible *by definition*.

The closest you can get is to use one specific GUID to stand in for a null value - `Guid.Empty` (also available as `default(Guid)` where appropriate, e.g. for the default value of an optional parameter) being the obvious candidate, but one you've rejected for unspecified reasons.

Comment: And to elaborate a little, it's non-nullable because it's a struct and thus a value type. Value types cannot be null. `Nullable<T>` can wrap a value type in a different value type that can represent a null value. If you were to make it `Nullable<Guid>` or `Guid?` for short, you can represent the DB side as a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL`

Comment: @DavidHaney: No, you've misunderstood `Nullable<T>` - that's a value type too, but it has a value representing the absence of a wrapped value. `Nullable<T>` would be a lot less pleasant if it were genuinely a reference type.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realize that. I'll disassemble and stare at it now. Thanks for the free lesson. :) On a side note, why would it be a lot less pleasant as a reference type?

Comment: @DavidHaney: Because then you'd have to create an instance (on the heap) for every value, rather than the value being "inline" - that would lead to more GC pressure.

Comment: @JonSkeet I cannot use Guid.Empty because I want it to be a default value for method parameter. As compiler points out "Default parameter value for X must be a compile-time constant"!

Comment: @KishanVaishnav: You can use `default(Guid)` for that. It's equivalent to `Guid.Empty`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. If you update the answer with this would be helpful for some people.

Comment: Guid.Empty is the best solution for me  Tanx

Answer (score 38):

```
Guid? myGuidVar = (Guid?)null;
```

It could be. Unnecessary casting not required.

```
Guid? myGuidVar = null;
```

Comment: Interesting comment that if you have a nullable Guid, it should be concreted as nullable everywhere (I mean even as parameter inside a method).

Comment: This helped me where db returns a strring, model expects Nullable GUID

UserRoleID = String.IsNullOrEmpty(userrole.RoleId) ? (Guid?)null : new Guid(userrole.RoleId);

thanks

Comment: How did this get 18 upvotes when the question clearly states it's not a valid answer? Was this merged from another question?

Answer (score 24):

Since "Guid" is not nullable, use "Guid.Empty" as default value.

Answer (score 9):

Choose your poison - if you can't change the type of the property to be nullable then you're going to have to use a "magic" value to represent NULL.  `Guid.Empty` seems as good as any unless you have some specific reason for not wanting to use it.  A second choice would be  `Guid.Parse("ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff")` but that's a lot uglier IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `typeof(Guid), "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"` for DefaultValue of the property.

Answer (score 3):

you can make guid variable to accept null first using ? operator then you use Guid.Empty or typecast it to null using (Guid?)null;

eg:

```
 Guid? id = Guid.Empty;
```

or

```
 Guid? id =  (Guid?)null;
```

Comment: The question clearly states that they cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct way:

Guid filed = Guid.Empty;

Answer (score 0):

extrac Guid values from database functions:

```
    #region GUID

    public static Guid GGuid(SqlDataReader reader, string field)
    {
        try
        {
            return reader[field] == DBNull.Value ? Guid.Empty : (Guid)reader[field];
        }
        catch { return Guid.Empty; }
    }

    public static Guid GGuid(SqlDataReader reader, int ordinal = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            return reader[ordinal] == DBNull.Value ? Guid.Empty : (Guid)reader[ordinal];
        }
        catch { return Guid.Empty; }
    }

    public static Guid? NGuid(SqlDataReader reader, string field)
    {
        try
        {
            if (reader[field] == DBNull.Value) return (Guid?)null; else return (Guid)reader[field];
        }
        catch { return (Guid?)null; }
    }

    public static Guid? NGuid(SqlDataReader reader, int ordinal = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            if (reader[ordinal] == DBNull.Value) return (Guid?)null; else return (Guid)reader[ordinal];
        }
        catch { return (Guid?)null; }
    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a .Net SqlCommand that calls a stored procedure, you can set the parameter to NULL using code like that below.

```
SqlCommand cmdCust = new SqlCommand("MyProc", myConn);    
cmdCust.Parameters.Add("@CustID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = DBNull.Value;
```